# RavenDB and IDocumentStoreListener

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listener, ravendb

I am trying to add an autoincrement to a simple model via an IDocumentStoreListener. I have found that the documentation regarding implementation of this feature is fairly sparse (any pointers would be greatly appreciated). I have been trying to follow [this blog post](http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/using-a-ravendb-listener-to-update-entities) but it appears to be out of date. When i try to implement

```
store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
{
    RunInMemory = true
}
.RegisterListener(new AuditableEntityListener(() => "Test User"))
.Initialize();
```

I get a build error stating "**Cannot convert lambda expression to type Raven.Client.IDocumentStore because it is not a delegate type**".

I managed to get it to build by using this code

```
store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
    {
        RunInMemory = true
    }
    .RegisterListener(new AuditableEntityListener(store ))
    .Initialize();
```

The code for the listener is as follows

```
public class PublicIdStoreListener : IDocumentStoreListener
    {

        HiLoKeyGenerator generator;
        IDocumentStore store;
        public PublicIdStoreListener(IDocumentStore store)
        {
            this.store = store;
            generator = new HiLoKeyGenerator(store, "verifications", 1024);
        } 

        public void AfterStore(string key, object entityInstance, RavenJObject metadata)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool BeforeStore(string key, object entityInstance, RavenJObject metadata)
        {
            var verification = entityInstance as VerifyAccountModel;
            if (verification.PublicId == "0")
            {
                verification.PublicId = generator.GenerateDocumentKey(store.Conventions, entityInstance);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

However, when i run  the application it hits the PublicIdStoreListener when any document is stored, not just the VerifyAccountModel, which causes the application to throw an exception.

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction on this as I am confused as to how this is actually supposed to be implemented. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I updated the documentlistener to the following

```
public bool BeforeStore(string key, object entityInstance, RavenJObject metadata)
        {

            if (entityInstance.GetType() == new VerifyAccountModel().GetType())
            {
                var verification = entityInstance as VerifyAccountModel;
                if (verification.PublicId == "0")
                {
                    verification.PublicId = generator.GenerateDocumentKey(store.Conventions, entityInstance);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

**UPDATE**
I figured out that i cant attach the store via RegisterListener in the same line that it is instantiated. It has to be done afterwards otherwise the store is still null when passed in. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if there's a way to register the listener to only fire for certain types, but you can certainly structure your code to only process `VerifyAccountModel` entities.

```
var verification = entityInstance as VerifyAccountModel;
if (verification == null) 
    return false; // We can't do anything, just let it pass through
```

Also, **my understanding is that you should return true when you make a change, false if no change was made**. This determines whether the entity needs to be re-serialized. If that is correct, the whole thing might be restructured as follows.

```
var verification = entityInstance as VerifyAccountModel;
if (verification != null && verification.PublicId == "0")
{
    verification.PublicId = generator.GenerateDocumentKey(store.Conventions, entityInstance);
    return true; // change made, re-serialize
}

return false; // no change made
```

Comment: David - so the line **.RegisterListener(new AuditableEntityListener(() => "Test User"))** is incorrect and I am adding this to documentstore correctly using **.RegisterListener(new AuditableEntityListener(store ))**?

Comment: Yes, your `PublicIdStoreListener` constructor is written to accept `IDocumentStore`.

Comment: You are using `PublicIdStoreListener` right? `AuditableEntityListener` is just coming from copy/paste of the blog post?

Comment: so i updated the IDocumentStoreListener to follow your suggestions but now I am getting a NullReferenceException on store.Conventions. Any ideas? Also, do you know where I can suitable documentation for this feature?

Comment: @jamesamuir Right. Looking at your code more closely, that's to be expected. At the point where you say `new AuditableEntityListener(store )`, you have not yet actually assigned `store`. That assignment doesn't happen until the chained calls have all returned. In other words, you're basically saying `new AuditableEntityListener(null )`. You could restructure this: `store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { RunInMemory = true }.Initialize(); store.RegisterListener(new PublicIdStoreListener(store));`